# Pass url parameters to a swf (flash) movie

Tags: flash

Flash newbie here.

I am trying to load a swf file in a browser and pass url parameters to the flash movie. How do I access the url parameters in the flash movie in actionscript?

Here is an example url:

http://www.server.com/swf/movie.swf?name=charlie&position=2

I did find pointers on passing parameters through embed/object tags, but nothing on passing url parameters (and accessing them) just through a browser url.

Thanks for the help,

Wilbur

Answer (score 3):

They show up in `loaderInfo.parameters`, just like FlashVars.  For example, `loaderInfo.parameters['name']` should return `'charlie'`.