# Load flash builder app from a URl

Tags: apache-flex, url, flash

I have an browser based application built with Flash Builder (actually Flex 3.5) with a Java backend. The application works well. It has a default login page and users can always login and view products by typing the product id in an input field to display product and other info.

I will like to modify this application in such a way that a product page can be viewed by just including the product id in the url something like www.myserver.com/?product_id=1234577

I am completely at lost on how to implement this and not even sure if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible.

The key details are from [Pass url parameters to a swf (flash) movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774992/pass-url-parameters-to-a-swf-flash-movie):

Look at `loaderInfo.parameters["product_id"]` in your Flex code; as your application initializes, hook into your current logic that brings up info when you type in a product ID.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [this approach](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) . You can pass parameters like (if embedded in jsp page)

> var flashvarsWF = {};
>
> flashvarsWF.product_id= '<%=productId%>';

And you can pass this flashvarsWF  in

> swfobject.embedSWF()

In flex main application(mxml), you can receive this as

> var pId:String = this.parameters.productId;