# Purpose of ?debug=prompt when passed to a .swf file

Tags: flash, xss

We have a .swf file and when it is invoked as player.swf?debug=prompt(/hi/), it opens a (javascript like) prompt dialog with /hi/ as title and a text input field.

Tried googling for it and did not find anything relevant.
Can someone explain purpose of this mechanism?
Does this qualify as an XSS attack if such a URL is clicked by a user?

Thanks,
Sameer

[image]

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774992/pass-url-parameters-to-a-swf-flash-movie

Comment: `?debug=prompt` is not a standard thing within every .swf file. Likely whoever made your swf just programmed it that way (eg: `if URL variable "debug" = "prompt" then show textbox`... just an example pseudo-code).

Comment: @VC.One Please submit your comment as answer and I will accept it.